# P2P vs Client Server Architecture

Tags: networking, client-server, p2p

which one to choose between p2p or client-server network architecture for advanced file sharing option with less resources and manpower. will u illustrate with strong opinion??

I would like to know more if anyone can intrude between and get access between the two users in P2P??

Comment: This question doesn't describe the context. From which point of view, user or developer? For what purpose, free software or commercial?

Answer (score 1):

For long run and big scale I will obviously pick client-server mode.
It's indeed need more resources at the beginning than the P2P, but it's way more manageable (both in software and hardware) and make my life easier to maintain the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Client server mode is only useful if you are planning to do the file sharing within LAN, otherwise you need to have a public IP. The PC with public IP acts as a server. If you have a p2p file sharing system then you probably need only one server with public IP for the rendezvous and hole punching process. so many PC can connect with each other and share. What do you mean by advance file sharing ?